# Label does not show username in MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to start saying that I am new to MVC web app.
In debug I simply get my username, then there is a label that displays it, in my case it is nsanta.  It works when I am in debug but it does not in the IIS published version.  This is the text I get in the label when I go to the website
"IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool"

This is the code that works in debug.  They all work, it is just different ways I have tried:

In the **Controller**:

1. `public string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;`
2. `var testuserName = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;`
3. ````
   var testuserName = testanotheruser.Name;
   ViewBag.Name = testuserName;```
   ````

In the **View**:

```
@Html.Label((string)ViewBag.Name)
```

Again, they all work in debug but when I go to the website it does not.

Also, I do not know if it matters but I included a screenshot of the project properties. Another forum mentioned to set Anonymous Authentication to Disabled and Windows Authentication to Enabled.  The second screenshot shows authentication in IIS.  Please help, I do not know what else to do.

[image]

[image]

Comment: When using 'Anonymous Authentication' no username will be available. So you need to enable 'Windows Authentication' in your IIS.

Comment: This was the answer, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `Anonymous Authentication` enabled in IIS. Disable that and enable `Windows Authentication`. (You have both options in the last picture)

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the answer!

Comment: I had to make (1)Anonymous Authentication to Disabled  and  (2)Windows Authentication to Enabled in both the project properties and in the IIS Authentication.